# Required Background modes key is not there in info-plist file

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, info-plist

I want to set required background mode key value so that my app also works in background. Actually i want to get the user location updates when the app is in background, but there is no key called required background mode key in my info-plist file. How to set this key and jow to bring this in my file?

Comment: You just add it to the info.plist.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Xcode 5,  **Project setting -> Target -> Capabilities -> Background modes -> check Location updates.**

If you are using an earlier version of Xcode, set the background mode for Location as in the following screenshot.

[image: plist background modes]

Comment: Is this a BUG? when Required background modes > "App provides Voice over IP services" is selected then instead of GREEN UI it shows a RED ui on top. Also in iPad the RED ui say its recording but my app does not do recording it only do Voice over.

Comment: I am still getting this issue and some more https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/issue-in-firebase-push-notification-in-ios/128842.please have a look

Comment: Could not find Background modes under Signing & Capabilities (Xcode 11.1)

Answer (score 12):

In Xcode 5, Select your app, then enabled background modes and select location updates

**Target > Capabilities**

[image: Xcode background mode settings screenshot]

Answer (score 12):

You can add that key to the info.plist. If you are using Xcode 5 it's very simple. In Capabilities just turn on the Background Modes.

[image: Xcode Capabilities screenshot]