# Schedule task every 2 minutes in jailbroken iOS app

Tags: ios, timer, scheduled-tasks, background-process, jailbreak

I am not one to support jailbreaking but I've exhausted all other options in the regular SDK.

Is there a way to schedule a function to run every 2 minutes even while the app is in the background and the phone's screen is off? It would also need to re-initialize the app in the event the phone had killed it. This is similar to an android foreground service.

Comment: What sort of function?

Comment: And for the record: I have tried to utilize both Background Fetch and Background Push. Apple limits silent push notifications and it seems to fail at night. This is why I am pursuing a jailbroken solution.

Comment: @crclayton The function makes a request to a REST API.

Comment: Which iOS version(s)?  Since you're opening this up to jailbroken OS's, have you considered a Launch Daemon?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried running it on a background thread using grand central dispatch, you'll also have to set up a background enabled key in the plist file, [Required Background modes key is not there in info-plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524421/required-background-modes-key-is-not-there-in-info-plist-file).

Edit:

You could also set up a silent two minute song to be played in background and then call your function within -(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying and repeat the song

Comment: That alone won't do it.  Unless you take special action, your background run time is still limited, and your app will be suspended within a fairly short amount of time.

Comment: I think you have 30 seconds a thread so you could set up a counter that goes up by one each thread and fires your notification at the 4th thread

Comment: You could also set up a silent two minute song to be played in background and then call your function within -(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying and repeat the song

Comment: I have no idea what your first comment means, but the second one (about silent audio) is useful.  You should move that to your *answer*, because without it, what you have there is insufficient to solve the OP's problem (hence the down vote by someone ... not I).