# Unable to get location after a day

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, geolocation, gps

I am working on an application in which I need get location in every 2 minutes and sending it to the server.

Its working fine for 22-24 hours but after that it just stop to send location until application came in the foreground.

Can please anyone let me know any reason for that?

Here is the code which I am using:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager];

locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
//locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: First try to determine if app stops receiving new locations or stops sending it to the server...

Comment: Its stops to receiving new location and also not sending to server. No matter location is same or new, it should always send location to the server but not sending after that.

Comment: Check `backgroundTimeRemaining`; it may be reaching 0. Once it does your app must return to the foreground before it can execute in the background.

Comment: check with this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: also make sure this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/21524637/4831524

Comment: @AntonyRaphel, No this was not my question. The background fetch is working around a day and after its stop to fetch the location. Is there any restriction in Apple?

Comment: Yes, you have to guide lines